# If $N^n=0$ but $N^{n-1}\neq 0$, then there is no $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that $A^2=N$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence, characteristic-polynomial

> Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and let $N$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over the field $F$ such that $N^n=0$ but $N^{n-1}\neq 0$. Prove that there is **no** $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that $A^2=N$.

I can understand that $N$ is nilpotent, and if there is such an $A$, then $A^{2n}=0$ which forces $A$ to be nilpotent as well. But I can't see any obvious way to use it to prove that such an $A$ doesn't exist. Also, I can't see how to relate the order of a matrix with the exponent.

Comment: Can you show that $A^{n+1} = 0$ implies $A^n=0$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring No, I can't see any obvious way to do that :(

Answer (score 3):

It is assumed that $n \neq 1$. $A^{2n}=0$ and this implies that $A^{n}=0$ (because $A$ is $n \times n$). Hence, $A^{k}=0$ for all $k \geq n$. But $2n-2 \geq n$ so $A^{2n-2}=0$. So $N^{n-1}=0$, a contradiction.

[To show tat $A^{n}=0$ observe that $0$ is the only eigne value. Use the fact that $p(A)=0$ where $p$ is the characteristic polynomial (Cayley Hamilton Theorem:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem )].

Comment: The fact that $A^n=0$ can also follow from the more elementary theorem that the sequence $\operatorname{rank}(A^k) \in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ is strictly decreasing until it stabilizes.  (of course we can use Cayley-Hamilton as well)

Comment: @kavi thanks for the answer (+1). I know the Cayley Hamilton Theorem but I can't understand how to prove $A^n=0$. I can see that since $A^{2n}=0$, then $\lambda =0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A^{2n}$. But, what does that tell us about $A$? Can you please help me out a little here...

Comment: @BrianMoehring can you please give a quick proof of this?

Comment: @SayanDutta What can you say about a polynomial of degree $n$ whose only root is $0$? It has to be of the type $p(z)=cz^{n}$ right?

Comment: Nothing like that. The ch. polynomial of $A$ must be of the form $cz^{n}$ (becasue its roots, the eigen values of $A$, are all $0$) and C-H Theorem implies that $cA^{n}=0$. @SayanDutta

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks, I understand